# Active admin without devise configuration on rails mountable engine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin, rails-engines

I am currently trying to install active admin on a rails mountable engine. The host application for the engine has authentication configured using devise. I have installed active admin without devise authentication using the --skip-user option [while running rake active_admin:install]. I am mounting the engine on the host application on the path /admin_app/.

When trying to access the URL:

```
http://localhost:3000/admin_app/admin
```

I am getting the following error

```
ActionController::RoutingError - uninitialized constant Admin::DashboardController:
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:57:in `rescue in   controller'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:52:in `controller'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:32:in `call'
journey (1.0.4) lib/journey/router.rb:68:in `block in call'
journey (1.0.4) lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:612:in `call'
railties (3.2.13) lib/rails/engine.rb:479:in `call'
railties (3.2.13) lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
journey (1.0.4) lib/journey/router.rb:68:in `block in call'
journey (1.0.4) lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:612:in `call'
newrelic_rpm (3.6.9.171) lib/new_relic/rack/error_collector.rb:50:in `call'
newrelic_rpm (3.6.9.171) lib/new_relic/rack/error_collector.rb:50:in `call'
newrelic_rpm (3.6.9.171) lib/new_relic/rack/agent_hooks.rb:28:in `call'
newrelic_rpm (3.6.9.171) lib/new_relic/rack/browser_monitoring.rb:23:in `call'
newrelic_rpm (3.6.9.171) lib/new_relic/rack/developer_mode.rb:42:in `call'
warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/best_standards_support.rb:17:in `call'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/head.rb:14:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:21:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:242:in `call'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:210:in `context'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:205:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:341:in `call'
activerecord (3.2.13) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:64:in `call'
activerecord (3.2.13) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:479:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:28:in `block in call'
activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `_run__342236532__call__311563165__callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_call_callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:65:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:31:in `call'
better_errors (1.0.1) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:84:in `protected_app_call'
better_errors (1.0.1) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:79:in `better_errors_call'
better_errors (1.0.1) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:56:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:16:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:56:in `call'
railties (3.2.13) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:32:in `call_app'
railties (3.2.13) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `block in call'
activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:22:in `tagged'
railties (3.2.13) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:22:in `call'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
activesupport (3.2.13) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:63:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.13) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:63:in `call'
railties (3.2.13) lib/rails/engine.rb:479:in `call'
railties (3.2.13) lib/rails/application.rb:223:in `call'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
railties (3.2.13) lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:17:in `call'
rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:59:in `service'
/home/systemone/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
/home/systemone/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
/home/systemone/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p448/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:191:in `block in start_thread'
```

Comment: What version of Active Admin are you using?

Comment: Active admin version is 0.6.1

Comment: 0.6.0 had a bug with similar symptoms: https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/issues/2049

But that was fixed as of 0.6.1. Maybe you should open a new ticket?